# Assigning AJAX response for two separate DIV tags

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax call code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                   
        $('#itemcode').blur(function(){
                var itemcode = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:'ajax.php',
                        data: {'itemcode' : itemcode} ,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data)
                        $("#desc").val(data);
                        $("#bal").val(data);
                        }
                    });
            });

    });
 </script>

include "db.php";
$itemcode=$_POST['itemcode'];

$sql="select * from itemmaster where Item_Code='$itemcode'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['Item_Desc'];
echo $row['Balance_Stock'];
}
```

This is simple html form..

```
<form action="add.php" method="post">
<table style="border: 1px solid black;padding:20px;"cellspacing="1px">
</br></br>
<tr>
<td>Issue No:</td> <td><input name="issueno" type="text" id="issueno"/></td>
<td>Issue Date:</td> <td><input name="issuedate" type="date" id="issuedate"/></td></tr></br></br><tr></tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Item Code:</td> <td><input name="itemcode" type="text" id="itemcode" /></td>
 <td>Description:</td> <td><input name="des" type="text" style="width:250px; height:23px" id="desc"/></td>
 <td>Bal Quantity:</td> <td><input name="bal" type="text" id="bal"/></td>
 </tr></br>
<tr> <td>Issue Quantity:</td> <td><input name="issuequ" type="text" id="issuequ"/></td></tr></br><tr></tr>
<tr><td>Remark:</td> <td><input name="remark" type="text" style="width:250px; height:23px" id="remark"/></td></tr></br>

<tr><td colspan="6"><center><input type="submit" value="submit"></center></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

When I alert(data) I am getting this samsung20.00. where samsung is description and 20.00 is bal. I want to assign description desc id an bal to bal id. So How do I do that??

Comment: Are you using json_encode function when you call ajax.php? if so, you need to parse `data` when you get response.

Comment: @AnkurBhadania see my edit above...

Comment: Actually which answer I implemented, that answer is not here now..may be that person deleted his answer..

Answer (score 3):

In your ajax.php file, you need to use json_encode function so you can parse it after get response:

```
include "db.php";
$itemcode=$_POST['itemcode'];

$sql="select * from itemmaster where Item_Code='$itemcode'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$json = array("Item_Desc" = > $row['Item_Desc'],
              "Balance_Stock" => $row['Balance_Stock']
              );
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

After making adjusts that you can encode your response, Your ajax need to parse it.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $('#itemcode').blur(function(){
            var itemcode = $(this).val();

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    data: {'itemcode' : itemcode} ,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#desc").html(obj.Item_Desc);
                    $("#bal").html(obj.Balance_Stock);
                    }
                });
        });

});
```

Its very simple.

Hope it helps you

Comment: If you specify `dataType: 'json'` on the `$.ajax()` calls options it will automatically parse the response as JSON for you, and pass the resulting object/array as the first parameter of the success function.

Comment: This is another good option as well. But at first acknowledge, this can be useful when you don't have skills and want to understand json.

Answer (score 1):

in your php file join the value `Samsung` and `20.00` with `||` sign

```
include "db.php";

$itemcode=$_POST['itemcode'];

$sql="select * from itemmaster where Item_Code='$itemcode'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['Item_Desc'].'||'.$row['Balance_Stock'];
}
```

java script code add the var response = data.split('||'); function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
            $('#itemcode').blur(function(){
                    var itemcode = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:'ajax.php',
                            data: {'itemcode' : itemcode} ,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert(data)
                            var response = data.split('||');//spilt the value 
                            $("#desc").val(response[0]);
                            $("#bal").val(response[1]);
                            }
                        });
                });

        });
     </script>
```

Comment: There's this thing called JSON that is perfect for this kind of thing, and doesn't require you to add separators, split strings, or worry about whether any of your actual data might end up having your separator in it.

Comment: This is trully **Workaround-oriented programming**

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                   
            $('#itemcode').blur(function(){
                    var itemcode = $(this).val();

                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url:'ajax.php',
                            data: {'itemcode' : itemcode} ,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(data) {
                                alert(data)

                           var str1 = data.replace(/\d.+/g, '');  
                           var str2 = data.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');

                            $("#desc").val(str1);
                            $("#bal").val(str2);
                            }
                        });
                });

        });
     </script>
```