# How to pass different information into separate divs based on ajax, jquery call from mysql w?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Basically I am trying to pass multiple columns from a mysql data base into multiple separate divs. Below is the ajax code I am using, I am not sure if that is the only information that is needed so if you need more feel free to let me know. I got it to pull the other columns however when the Jquery/ajax combination gets called it pulls all the information into all the divs.

I added the other IDs below the console log but ultimately it just added it to the same div like stated above. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! In the mean time ill continue my search for an answer as well.

enter code here

```
//jquery
             var ID=$(this).val();
            if  (ID){
                //ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url:'GetAllData.php',
                    data: 'Fullname='+ID,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        console.log(html)
                        $('#ID').html(html);
                    },
                });
            }else{
                $('#ID').html('<value="">ID NOT LOADED</select>');
            }
        });
```

PHP

```
    $Fullname=$_POST['Fullname'];

    if(!empty($_POST['Fullname']))


     {

   $query=$conn->query("SELECT Supervisor, Fullname, ID, BalancedScore, 
   IncentiveMonth FROM SomeTable WHERE ID= '".$Fullname."'order by Fullname 
   ASC");

    $rowCount=$query->num_rows;

if($rowCount>0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {


   $a = array ("ID[]" => $row['ID'], "BalancedScore[0]" => 
   $row['BalancedScore'], "Fullname[1]" => $row['Fullname']);
            print_r(array_values($a));

    }


}else{

    echo '<option value=""> Agent Value Not Available </option>';



    }
}
```

HTML

```
  <select name="agent" id="agent">
  <option value="">Select Agent</option>
  </select>

           </div>

           <div class="ID_Container">

           <div name="ID" id="ID" >

           ID

    </div>
    </div>

           <div name="BalancedScore" id="BalancedScore" >

           Balanced Score

    </div>
```

Comment: Please show your html and complete js code.

Comment: I edited it with the code that I am using.

Comment: In your php file you are returning option, but you are appending html to the div#ID . Why? Your code is confusing just tell me what exactly do you want so I can figure it out?

Comment: I am attempting to get an array from my sql. Its to show an agents score. So its going to have things like call time, ids, scores, etc. I want it to populate on change, different divs. I changed the PHP so instead of the row values above i changed it to ------

echo json_encode(array("IEX_ID" => $row['IEX_ID'], "BalancedScore" => $row['BalancedScore'], "Fullname" => $row['Fullname'])); --------

but I am still have some problems getting it to return the value into the divs. It does however return fine in the console.

Comment: Update your code here.

Comment: I updated the code in my original question to reflect what I changed. Now it populates in the console as an array with [] [1] [2] which im assuming I want. It changes the divs blank when I switch agent name so I am assuming im on the right track. Just not grasping how to get that array information into individual divs of my choice based on ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I made an array with my php code and encoded it.

```
$output = array ("IEX_ID" => $row['IEX_ID'], "BalancedScore" => 
$row['BalancedScore'], "Fullname[2]" => $row['Fullname']);

echo json_encode($output);
```

Then I changed my 
ajax to the below code and finally it adds my array to their respective divs. I used this link to help me if anyone needs help in the future. [Assigning AJAX response for two separate DIV tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190470/assigning-ajax-response-for-two-separate-div-tags)

```
            $(document).on('change', "#agent", function(event) { 

        //jquery
         var IEX_ID=$(this).val();

        if  (IEX_ID){
            //ajax call
            $.ajax({

                type:'POST',
                url:'GetAllData.php',
                cache:false,
                data: 'Fullname='+IEX_ID,
                success: function(data){


                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    alert(obj);

                    $('#IEX_ID').html(obj.IEX_ID);
                    $('#BalancedScore').html(obj.BalancedScore);
```